# What does $product.allow_oosp mean in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I cannot find what does $product.allow_oosp stand from and from where does this variable gets it's data ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

allow_oosp means allow out of stock products ordering for product. If you go to admin then Preferences -> Products , on that page in the Product Stock section, you will find  **" Allow ordering of out-of-stock products "** , this is for allow_oosp.

Thank you